# PDO Insert multiple rows into MySQL a table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to insert multiple lines in a single query based on this example:
 [a link][1]: http://thisinterestsme.com/pdo-prepared-multi-inserts/

But the values are not inserted.

```
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->database", $this->login, 
$this->password);
    $columnNames = array_keys($dataVals[0]);
    unset($columnNames["8"]);
    unset($columnNames["9"]);
    foreach ($dataVals as $arrayIndex => $row) {
        $params = array();
        foreach ($row as $columnName => $columnValue) {
            $param = ":".$columnName.$arrayIndex;
            $params[] = $param;
            $toBind[$param] = $columnValue;
        }
        $rowsSQL[] = "(".implode(", ", $params).")";
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$this->table` (".implode(", ", $columnNames).") VALUES ".implode(", ", $rowsSQL);
    $pdoStatement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($toBind as $param => $val) {
        $pdoStatement->bindParam($param, $val);
    }
    $pdoStatement->execute();
```

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: Now I want try PDO,  because I use pure php

Comment: If you want to learn, that's great, but learn from good examples. There's nothing "pure" about core PHP. It's just the foundation people build code on top of. [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) is an important resource, and ignoring it is not going to help you learn, it's going to cut you off from an important source of learning.

Comment: Could you provide `$dataVals` in your example? Please also print and post final `$sql` string and `$toBind` array. Have you checked the error log?

Comment: Be very careful with this: `".implode(", ", $columnNames)."`  Any time you concatenate anything you must make sure it is clean.  For example if you allow `$_POST['name'] => 'Joe Smith'` and you take that key `name` and use it for a column name, you just opened yourself up for SQL Injection.  You can get the table schema `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table` right from the DB, but this should be cached as it's an expensive lookup to add to each query.  Then you can use that to filter the column names (white list).

Comment: Why do you remove 2 items from `$columnNames`? Later you iterate over all properties of an item of `$dataVals` array. This looks like a bug. The columns and columns-values have to be consistent.

Comment: This 2 items not need in database.

Comment: Then you need to ignore them also in the loop `foreach ($row as $columnName => $columnValue) {` otherwise you generate more params than you have columns.